# How can I create a Map of ArrayLists without knowing how many ArrayLists I will need?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist

The way my program works is it gets an arraylist of some object "World". I want to create a new arraylist for every World. I then want to create a map where the name of a World is the key, and a arraylist is the value. So far, I can get an unique id for each World and the size of the arraylist of Worlds, but I don't know how to create that map.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The point of a map is that you don't need to know how many entries it will have in advance.

Comment: You don't need to know how many elements there are in order to populate a `Map`.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the classes that implement the Map interface, e.g. HashMap:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<World>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<World>>();
```

Comment: Prefer declaring against the interface over the implementation.

Comment: Specifying the variable as a Map interface is better than a HashMap object. Also, there are many other classes besides HashMap that [implement the Map interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Comment: You're still using ArrayList instead of List. The map should be a Map<String, List<World>>.